# jQuery Form gets lost after Bootstrap modal is cloned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My idea is to submit myForm which is placed inside Bootstrap modal via jQueryForm, with immediate upload status response to user. It works fine until I try to reset myForm by cloning myModal. After cloning everything looks fine untill you try to submit myForm once again. The result is that instead of getting myStatus filled in I am redirected to upload_replay-echo.php. Solution is easy: location.reload() but it makes the whole idea completely pointless.

The code below is a working example. The upload_replay-echo.php can return anything. For example:

```
<?php
echo 'Upload echo..<br>';
?>
```

Can anyone help me in this matter?

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.2.3/bootstrap-table.min.css">
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.2.3/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(window).load(function(){
            var myBackup = $('#myModal').clone();
            // Delegated events because we make a copy, and the copied button does not exist onDomReady
            $('body').on('click','#myReset',function() {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide').remove();
                var myClone = myBackup.clone();
                $('body').append(myClone);

                // location.reload();

            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Modal starter.. -->
        <div class="container">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Start modal
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal.. -->
        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">File to upload</h4>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
                        <form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_replay-echo.php" method="post" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Upload file" />
                            <input type="file" name="myfile[]" multiple title="Choose WoT replay files to upload" size="100" class="btn-sm"/>
                        </form>

                        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Important: <small>If you can see any text below then please use "Reset" button before trying to upload any file.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div id="myStatus"></div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal Body - end -->
                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" id="myReset">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- File upload tests: jQuery.Form --> 
        <script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
        <script>
        (function() {

        var bar = $('.progress-bar');
        var status = $('#myStatus');

        $('form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function() {
                status.empty();
                var pcv = '0%';
                bar.width(pcv);
            },
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var pcv = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(pcv);
            },
            success: function() {
                var pcv = '100%';
                bar.width(pcv);
            },
            complete: function(xhr) {
                var pcv = '0%';
            //  Wait 1 second and reset progress..
                setTimeout(function (){
                    bar.width(pcv);
                }, 1000);
                status.html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }); 

        })();
        </script>
    <!-- File upload tests: jQuery.Form - end -->   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized ajaxForm is just one time initialize! when you reset the modal related Form - dom element unbind from jquery form plugin.
You should prepareForm (Instantiation) everytime  when reset the modal.

```
    var myUploadModule = myUploadModule || {};
    $(window).load(function() {
        myUploadModule.myBackup = $('#myModal').clone();
        myUploadModule.init = function() {
            var _this = this;
            console.log("my module initializer");
            // Delegated events because we make a copy, and the copied button does not exist onDomReady
            $('body').on('click','#myReset',function() {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide').remove();
                var myClone = _this.myBackup.clone();
                $('body').append(myClone);

                myUploadModule.prepareForm();
                // location.reload();
            });

            myUploadModule.prepareForm();
        };
        myUploadModule.prepareForm = function() {
            var bar = $('.progress-bar');
            var status = $('#myStatus');

            $('form').ajaxForm({
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    status.empty();
                    var pcv = '0%';
                    bar.width(pcv);
                },
                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var pcv = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(pcv);
                },
                success: function() {
                    var pcv = '100%';
                    bar.width(pcv);
                },
                complete: function(xhr) {
                    var pcv = '0%';
                //  Wait 1 second and reset progress..
                    setTimeout(function (){
                        bar.width(pcv);
                    }, 1000);
                    status.html(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        };

        myUploadModule.init();
    });
```